# Placing HTML comment tags within HTML comment tags

Tags: html, tags, comments

So, this is probably a very specific use case, but here we go.

I'm helping a company who is sending a section of HTML code out to a group of us, where we will be taking data from an excel sheet, and placing it in the appropriate spots in HTML to fill in the table.  I'm working to help clean it up so it makes sense to people who don't really do coding normally, as they don't need to understand the code as long as they know where to put the data.  I was going to put a comment block up at the top of the document with a few notes, one of which would talk about the `<!-- and -->` tags.  What I'm worried about, is since that note would be nested within comment tags, would the --> tag within the comment close the comment, and cause the rest of the note to be read as code? Sample line of code below.

```
<!--Begin instructions for editing. Make sure you change the information between the <td></td> tags, and not the <!-- --> tags. End instructions for editing.-->
```

Is there a way to have that be a valid comment in HTML, and the comment not be closed out until the second --> tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once comment section get the --> it will terminate comment.
So you need to replace --> with any other e.g. ~~> etc...

Your code can be:

```
<!--Begin instructions for editing. Make sure you change the information between the <td></td> tags, and not the <!~~ ~~> tags. End instructions for editing.-->
```

Answer (score 1):

No. See [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#comments).

> Comments must have the following format:
>
> 1. The string "`<!--`".
> 2. Optionally, text, with the additional restriction that the text must not start with the string "`>`", nor start with the string
>      "`->`", **nor contain the strings "`<!--`", "`-->`", or "`--!>`"**,
>      nor end with the string "`<!-`".
> 3. The string "`-->`".